# jQuery validation for HTML elements with language support (Japanese)

Tags: jquery, validation, cjk, lang

I have applied custom validation techniques and messages for my application. I have used validation for HTML fields like this:

Number only fields - > assigned input tags with data-type='number' or type='number' and handled in scripts with digits ASCII characters to be allowed in the particular field.

Every field which is mandatory has an attribute; required and same is handled for validation for empty entries.

The above two example validations are used in our application. The issue is now that our application is also used by Japanese clients; all validations work fine for English, but in Japanese everything goes this/that way.

For fields, type='number' in Japanese - hiragana mode we can type in Japanese characters and numbers both. Date fields are taking input likewise ２６．０６．２０１３ instead of 26/06/2013

How can we achieve validation for both English and Japanese at one go?

I have seen http://jqueryvalidation.org/ which validates a form only. We are in need for anything that needs to be validated (onclick/div/anything); I believe the above link will not be helpful to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression.

```
var datePattern = /^([0-9０-９]{1,2}[./．]){2}[0-9０-９]{4}$/;
datePattern.test('２６．０６．２０１３'); // true
datePattern.test('1/1/1969'); // true
```

I haven't checked if using unicode characters in a regex like this works in all browsers. In case it doesn't, you could always escape them:

```
var datePattern = /^([0-9\uFF10-\uFF19]{1,2}[./\uFF0E]){2}[0-9\uFF10-\uFF19]{4}$/;
```